# How to fix 'FacebookTokenError: Error validating verification code.'

Tags: node.js, facebook, api

When trying to login using Facebook, I get the following error message:

```
FacebookTokenError: Error validating verification code.
Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the
OAuth dialog request
```

The url in the OAuth dialog request is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Furl.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile&client_id=<id here>
```

In the Facebook Login settings of the app I've added every variation of the url I could think of:

```
https://url.com/auth/facebook/callback
https://url.com/auth/facebook/callback/
https://url.com/auth/facebook/callback?code=
https://url.com/auth/facebook/callback?scope=email,public_profile&client_id=<id here?
```

What URL am I supposed to add?

Comment: This is about the API call you make to exchange the code for a token, after the user got redirected back to your app. In that API call, you need to supply the exact same redirect_uri value, as was used in the login dialog call. Most frameworks/libraries are able to handle that automatically, if the login process was started from the same URL, but if it was a different one or you aren’t using any frameworks, you might need to explicitly specify it yourself.

Comment: Is "the API call you make to exchange the code for a token" not the URL I pasted above? The one that provides a client_id and has a response_type set to code?

Comment: No, that is where you redirect the user to in the front end, to show the login dialog. The user gets redirected back to your app (to the redirect_uri specified in the login dialog call), and there your app then needs to make the API call (in the background) to exchange the code for a token.